# Can choices in a list be changed after it has been been rendered?

Tags: w2ui

I have a w2ui form that contains a w2ui Drop List of choices.  The choices will be different depending on what the user selected to bring up the form. My question is:  can the contents of a Drop List be changed after it has been rendered?

With standard HTML controls, I would do something like this:

```
$("#mySelect option[value='xyz']").remove();
```

or

```
$("#mySelect").append('<option value="abc">abc</option>');
```

Can these kinds of operations be done with a w2ui Drop List?  Any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In w2ui 1.5 you can use `$jQueryElement.w2field()` to access the w2fild object - and then manipulate it.

Example:

```
var field = $("#my_input").w2field();
field.options.items = ["my", "new", "items"];
// optionally: pre-select first item
field.setIndex(0);
// if you do NOT use "setIndex" you need to call "refresh" yourself!
// field.refresh();
```

Note: `setIndex()` internally calls `refresh()` - so as stated above, you do not need to call refresh yourself in that case.

If you want to **completely** clear/empty your field, you can call `field.reset()`.

---

Edit: after clarification that it's about a form field:

```
// Note: ``this`` refers to the w2form
// ``field[8]`` refers to a field of type "select"
  this.fields[8].options.items = ["my", "new", "items"];
  this.record = {
    field_select: 'new'
  };
  this.refresh();
```

Comment: Hi there mpf82. First, thanks for the suggestion.  Sorry for the delayed response, I got sidetracked, but now I'm back on the work involving w2ui.  I tried this, but the field value always comes back as null. It's probably something simple... here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sman/1kaodbbx/24/) http://jsfiddle.net/sman/1kaodbbx/24/   Click the Change List button.  Have a look at the JS code - lines 77-83.

Comment: Hi @sman , I thought you were talking about stand-alone fields. Changing fields in a form is a little bit different: http://jsfiddle.net/1kaodbbx/28/ - BTW in your example you were linking w2ui ``1.4`` sources, ``$().w2field()`` would not have worked anyway.

Comment: Hey mpf82 -- I did catch that 1.4 issue, and I updated to 1.5, but it looks like I forgot to save it. Sorry about that!  Anyway thanks, for providing working code, it's clear now.